# How can I add double quotes to a string parameter in Jenkins pipeline script

Tags: java, string, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins pipeline job.
The job is taking an input parameter as string.
I am able to retrieve that value from the script.

I wanted to add or enclose that string within double quotes. How can I achieve that?

**Input parameter : [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)**

In the script : echo InputLink

is printing me the value [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)

**Expected result**
**"www.google.com"**

Comment: I believe this will do: `echo "\"${InputLink}\""`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your pipeline code just add quotes to the input string.

Assuming your input parameter is called **Input**:

```
quoted_input = '"' + Input + '"'
```

```
//or using string interpolation 
quoted_input = "\"${Input}\""
```

Then you can use the `quoted_input` wherever you need the quoted value.

If you are using a declarative pipeline use a script block:

```
script {
    quoted_input = "\"${params.Input}\""
}
```

Or define it as an environment variable so it will be available for all stages:

```
pipeline {
    environment {
        QUOTED_INPUT = "\"${params.Input}\""
    }
    ...

}
```